# .Net: Does my connection get closed via Dispose in this example?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Here's a simplified version of my example:

```
using (DbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myProcedure", (SqlConnection)DataAccessHelper.CreateDatabase().CreateConnection()) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using(IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        doWork(dr);
}
```

When the command is disposed, is the connection closed?  Or would I need to have that first using statement be for the connection, and then create the command in the closure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the reader to close the connection, you can use the overload of ExecuteReader():

```
...
using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) 
...
```

By default, disposing a reader does not release the connection. - [see MSDN for more info...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx)

To address the question of `Close()` vs `Dispose()`, the MSDN states:

> If the DbConnection goes out of scope, it is not closed. Therefore,
>   you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose,
>   which are functionally equivalent.

Thus a self-closing connection need not be disposed necessarily.  The main difference is that a closed connection can be re-opened, but a disposed connection cannot.  The main additional work that `Dispose()` does is set internals to `null` which won't have much of an effect since the connection is passing out of scope anyway.

Comment: I don't believe that disposes the connection, just closes it.

Comment: Will this dispose the connection?

Comment: From the MSDN, calling Close() and Dispose() on a connection are functionally equivalent:

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare, can you provide a link? Even if, you probably should still dispose an IDisposable.

Comment: @MikeC: Ordinarily yes, you should, but there are some notable exceptions, for example even though Task implements IDisposable, it can throw if you dispose at incorrect times, so they recommend not disposing unless you are sure it's safe.

Answer (score 4):

James Michael Hare's works, but you'll also want to dispose of your connection. Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = (SqlConnection)DataAccessHelper.CreateDatabase().CreateConnection())
using (DbCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myProcedure", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using(IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        doWork(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a

```
using(var connection = (SqlConnection)DataAccessHelper.CreateDatabase().CreateConnection())
{
 connection.Open(); 
 ....
}
```

Because even if you close the connection, you still need to dispose it. Note that `SQLConnection` does call `Close` in the `Dispose`. The problem is that if you had to call `Close` yourself, you'd have to put it into a `try...catch` so it was guaranteed and you wouldn't have a memory leak. There are other types in the framework which don't call `Close` in the `Dispose`, which in my opinion should be wrapped.

Comment: The two lined "using" shown in my answer works great in this case.

Comment: @MikeC. Yes, I just wanted to rant about the different `Dispose` implementations.